# How to connect PHP with JSON type header

Tags: php, android, json, api

This is my PHP code

```
<?php require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php'; $response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password']) and isset($_POST['email']))
    {
        //operate the data further 

        $db = new DbOperations(); 

        $result = $db->createUser($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']);
        if($result == 1){
            $response['error'] = false; 
            $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
        }elseif($result == 2){
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = "Some error occurred please try again";          
        }elseif($result == 0){
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = "It seems you are already registered, please choose a different email and username";                     
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
    }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

when I using JSON type header it doesn't work

```
String jsonResult = null;
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("username", "33");
        jsonObject.put("password", "33");
        jsonObject.put("email", "33@gmail.com");

        jsonResult = jsonObject.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    String HitURL = "http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/Android/v1/registerUser.php";
    MediaType MEDIA_PlainMT = MediaType.parse("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(HitURL).post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_PlainMT, jsonResult)).build();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        TLSSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory=new TLSSocketFactory();
        if (tlsSocketFactory.getTrustManager()!=null) {
            client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .sslSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory, tlsSocketFactory.getTrustManager())
                    .build();
        }
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
            } else {
                String HitResponse = response.body().string();
                Log.v("/CheckLog/", HitResponse);
            }
        }
    });
```

the result

```
{"error":true,"message":"Required fields are missing"}
```

Comment: please write your sending code snippets

Comment: @ASHKARAN I update my post, and the code snipped that I used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server code expects submission of regular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` values (a.k.a. regular POST form submission) but your client is encoding your data in `application/json` (JSON object). Which of those should it be? The client and server must agree with each other.

Should you want to use JSON as your data encoding standard, your code should look something like this:

```php
<?php

require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $raw_input = file_get_contents('php://input');
    try {
      $input = json_decode($raw_input, TRUE, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
      if (isset($input['username']) and isset($input['password']) and isset($input['email']))
      {
          //operate the data further 

          $db = new DbOperations(); 

          $result = $db->createUser($input['username'],$input['password'],$input['email']);
          if($result == 1){
              $response['error'] = false; 
              $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
          }elseif($result == 2){
              $response['error'] = true; 
              $response['message'] = "Some error occurred please try again";          
          }elseif($result == 0){
              $response['error'] = true; 
              $response['message'] = "It seems you are already registered, please choose a different email and username";                     
          }

      }else{
          $response['error'] = true; 
          $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
      }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      $response['error'] = true; 
      $response['message'] = "Invalid Request: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I learn something from your answer thank you so much, but when I use your code it says something wrong in line 10, can you help what is missing? , <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\AllMyFiles\Featuring\Database\Program\Xampp\htdocs\Android\v1\registerUser.php:10
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\AllMyFiles\Featuring\Database\Program\Xampp\htdocs\Android\v1\registerUser.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />

Comment: I've forgot that json_decode gives you object by default. So the result `$input` values cannot be retrieved with `$input['key']`. I've changed the json_decode $assoc flag to TRUE and things should work fine now. Alternatively, you may get a certain key by `$input->key` instead. Both should work.

Comment: Thank you it's working now, JSON Object need to use $input->key, if I convert JSON object to the array  I need to use $input['key'] instead, thanks for your time :D